# Communication between two child components without causing a complete re-render in parent

Tags: reactjs

I've been learning and using ReactJS. After reading numerous threads and blog posts still I'm confused with having effective communication between components in ReactJS.

Let's say I've a parent component "A" and it has numerous child components "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" etc. Now something happened in the "a" component and I want to re-render the "b" component.

Since "a" and "b" has the same parent I can use the parent itself as the communication medium between this two. But the problem here is when I use parent as the communication medium it changes it's state and trigger the re-render and that'll cause the re-rendering of all the components "a", "c", "d", "e" etc. which I don't like it, instead I want to forcefully re-render only the "b" component.

Is this possible? How can I achieve this? Basically I want to do this for performance reasons.

Comment: Flux/Redux use some kind of event bus to communicate. So "a" posts a message in the bus and anybody who cares (in your case "b") responds to it. The others do not change. You can use Flux/Redux (they are considered good practice anyway), or you can implement some bus yourself. The bus can be shared through React's [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html).

Comment: I would highly recommend trying Redux. "Pure" React gets messy/tedious pretty quickly in any real-world app exactly for reasons like the one you posted.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way to do that, but...

JavaScript if fast and React reconciliation algorithm is also very fast. React will not re-render DOM, it will just check if there are changes in other components and apply if there are.

You can make what you want. For that you have [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html) function, which is called before rendering. So if you implement this function for your child components, they will not be re-rendered. However, it is recommended to use this function only of you really have issues with performance.

If you child components are simple and don't have deep trees of objects, you can use [shallow compare](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/shallow-compare.html) helper function. There is a probability that in future it will be included in all `pure` components by default.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally feasible using plain React. Your parent component need to act as a container and hold the state corresponding to the props of its children. When one of its child triggers an update, if you implement the `shouldComponentUpdate` method other child will not re-render. Here is a working snippet, if you checked / unchecked one of the item in the first list, all three items will re-render. In the second list bellow, only the targeted item will re-render.

```js
class ItemsList extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            items: {
                a: false,
                b: false,
                c: true
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        const self = this
        return (
            <ul>
                {Object.keys(self.state.items).map(
                    id => (
                        <Item
                            key={id}
                            id={id}
                            checked={self.state.items[id]}
                            handleChange={(e) => {
                                e.persist()
                                this.setState(state => ({
                                    ...self.state,
                                    items: {
                                        ...self.state.items,
                                        [id]: e.target.checked
                                    }
                                }))
                            }}/>
                    )
                )}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}


class Item extends React.Component {

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        return nextProps.checked != this.props.checked
    }

    render() {
        console.log(`rendering ${this.props.id}`)
        return (
            <li>
                <span>{this.props.id}</span>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={this.props.checked}
                    onChange={this.props.handleChange}/>
            </li>
        )
    }
}

class ItemsList2 extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            items: {
                a: false,
                b: false,
                c: true
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        const self = this
        return (
            <ul>
                {Object.keys(self.state.items).map(
                    id => (
                        <Item2
                            key={id}
                            id={id}
                            checked={self.state.items[id]}
                            handleChange={(e) => {
                                e.persist()
                                this.setState(state => ({
                                    ...self.state,
                                    items: {
                                        ...self.state.items,
                                        [id]: e.target.checked
                                    }
                                }))
                            }}/>
                    )
                )}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}


class Item2 extends React.Component {

    render() {
        console.log(`rendering ${this.props.id}`)
        return (
            <li>
                <span>{this.props.id}</span>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={this.props.checked}
                    onChange={this.props.handleChange}/>
            </li>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ItemsList/>, document.getElementById('app2'))

ReactDOM.render(<ItemsList2/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.0/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/react-addons-perf@latest"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
<div id="app2"></div>
```